# What type of gas(if it is not air) is a soccer ball (football) filled with?

Tags: rules, football, equipment

In any FIFA World Cup or UEFA competition or the Barclays Premier League and other professional football matches, what type of air is the ball filled with?

Are there any regulations on the type of air used?

Comment: HWy do you think I could not be air? Do you know any sport, balls are not filled with air? ...except from table tennis

Comment: It's be kind of fun to play with a ball filled with helium.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just plain old regular air. 78% nitrogen, 21% oxygen, 1% other stuff.